# How to debug a splice operation in a Perl script?

Tags: perl

```
#! usr/bin/perl
@months=('Jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec');
@new=('1','2');

print "@months\n";

splice(@months,0,1,@new);

print "@months\n";
```

When I run this I expect output to be as

```
Jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec
1 2 mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec
```

But I am getting output as

```
Jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec
1 2 feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec
```

The Feb should also be replaced by 2, right? But why it isn't happening.

Comment: check the documentation for splice. It says `Removes the elements designated by OFFSET and LENGTH from an array`. You are setting offset as 0 and length as 1. So starting at element 0 remove 1 element. Thats why only jan is removed.

Comment: Pro-tip: make your titles as useful as possible, and here "Can you please help me out" does not add anything to tempt readers to click on your question (and some people will avoid question that appear to contain begging).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Syntax of `splice` command is](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlfunc.pod#splice-ARRAY-OFFSET-LENGTH-LIST)

```
splice ARRAY,OFFSET,LENGTH,LIST
```

You specify `LENGTH` to be 1, so only one element is removed from the original list (that element is `Jan`). If you want `feb` to be removed too, then you must use a `LENGTH` of 2

```
splice(@months, 0, 2, @new);
```

Comment: Thank you. I presumed the syntax of the command as
    splice ARRAY,START_INDEX,END_INDEX,LIST.
That's why I got wrong.

Comment: @gudipatiramu - Always best to check the documentation that comes with your Perl install or check the documentation online.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle - Thank you for your advice. I will do it from the next time.